# ASP.net Search TextBox and Object that contains result

Tags: asp.net

Currently, I have a simple DropDownList, which contains around 100 entries. Searching for a specific entry is really uncomfortable and takes up alot of time, so I'm searching for the easiest/most efficient way to realize the following idea:

[image]

There are a few things you can see here, which I only show for a clear explanation. The only thing I want to know about is point 2 (question further down).

1. This is the Textbox I want to be able to search something with
2. This is the Object in which I want to show the result
3. The result consists of pictures. In the searchbox I can type in "Symbol1" and the result will be the picture Symbol1.png.
4. When hovering over, a note should pop up
5. A scrollbar should be available to scroll down inside that object

This is the result I want to achieve. My question is the following:

- **What kind of object would be most optimal to use for my example?**

I have looked into various possible solutions (Popup window, Searchable DropDownList, etc.), but I haven't found out which object I should use to show the result of a search in form of pictures.

Comment: Use a Repeater control in ASP.Net where you can freely decide the layout of items.

Comment: @Sunil Thank you. I'll have a look at it.

Comment: You can also freely write code against mouse over events for each item which will allow you to popup a note for item being hovered. You will need to use jquery for this.

Comment: @Sunil Alright. That's very helpful advice, thanks.